# PHP MYSQL While LOOP not displaying all rows

Tags: php, mysql, loops, while-loop

I'm trying to select all the rows from my database, where 'street' is LIKE the contents from an array ($streets).

Here's what I have...

```
    #TEXT AREA INPUT  = $streets
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `street` LIKE '%".implode("%' OR `street` LIKE     '%",$streets)."%'";
    echo $sql;
    $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql)  or die(mysql_error());
    $totalitems1 =  mysqli_num_rows($result);
    echo $totalitems1 . "<br>";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo $row['street']. "<br>";

    }
```

the varible $streets is exploded from a text area input, each value on a new line.

When I process this using PHP, only the rows that are LIKE the last 'OR' are returned .. (The last line in the text area).  But when I copy and paste the generated SQL into PHPMYADMIN, it returns ALL the data, as expected.

What am I missing here?  Thanks.

Comment: Try `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` instead of `mysqli_fetch_array()`

Comment: Sidenote: You're also mixing `mysqli_query` with an `mysql_*` function `mysql_error` which will result in not showing the actual error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess would be that you aren't stripping the newline from the end of each `$street` entry, therefore only the last entry looks valid as it probably doesn't have a trailing newline. No doubt your query probably looks like...

```
SELECT * FROM `data` WHERE `street` LIKE '%foo
%' OR `street` LIKE '%bar
%' OR `street` LIKE '%baz%'
```

The quick fix would be to use...

```
implode("%' OR `street` LIKE '%", array_map(function($s) use ($con) {
    return $con->escape_string(trim($s));
}, $streets))
```

Ideally, you should be using a prepared statement with parameter binding.

Comment: SUPER! Thank you very much.  I guess when you've been going all day, you look over the simple things.  Thanks again Phil.